# Reading from the beginning of a Kafka Topic using Structured Streaming when query started

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

im using structured streaming to read from the kafka topic, using `spark 2.4` and `scala 2.12`

im using a checkpoint to make my query fault-tolerant.

however everytime i start the query it jumps to the current offset without reading the exisitng data before it connected onto the topic.

is there a config for the kafka stream im missing?

READ:

```
 val df = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger","1")
    .option("startingOffset","earliest")
    .option("auto.offset.reset","earliest")
    .load()
val msg = df.select($"value" cast "string", $"topic", $"partition", $"offset")
```

Write:

```
val query= msg.writeStream
    .foreachBatch(
      (dfbatch: Dataset[Row], batchid: Long) =>
      {
      println(s"IM AT BATCH ID: $batchid")
      dfbatch.show()
      dfbatch.write.csv(s"s3a://abucket/$param")
      }
    )
      .option("checkpointLocation","s3a://checkpoint/")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
      .format("console")
      .start()

 query.awaitTermination()
```

EDIT:

here are the logs after i emptied my checkpoint dir:

```
0/07/11 18:15:16 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to s3a://checkpoint/metadata using temp file s3a://checkpoint/.metadata.304a751a-68b7-4b8d-858c-3aa5df272db4.tmp
20/07/11 18:15:17 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file s3a://checkpoint/.metadata.304a751a-68b7-4b8d-858c-3aa5df272db4.tmp to s3a://checkpoint/metadata
20/07/11 18:15:17 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting [id = e83c6066-9611-4e9b-97d5-d02421b2d1d6, runId = e77896e3-ce76-488b-8345-7a29cc0d7d0b]. Use s3a://checkpoint/ to store the query checkpoint.
20/07/11 18:15:17 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Using MicroBatchReader [KafkaV2[Subscribe[test]]] from DataSourceV2 named 'kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@2375c472]
20/07/11 18:15:17 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
20/07/11 18:15:17 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Stream started from {}
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 2.0.0
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO Metadata: Cluster ID: X8K8aVFyRi6OcUDs1zXOhQ
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Discovered group coordinator Myuser-PC:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] (Re-)joining group
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Successfully joined group with generation 1
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Setting newly assigned partitions [test-0]
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 0.
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 18.
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO deprecation: io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
20/07/11 18:15:18 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to s3a://checkpoint/sources/0/0 using temp file s3a://checkpoint/sources/0/.0.e900c0dd-dbb5-4ca7-ada2-e3a84e892c5f.tmp
20/07/11 18:15:19 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file s3a://checkpoint/sources/0/.0.e900c0dd-dbb5-4ca7-ada2-e3a84e892c5f.tmp to s3a://checkpoint/sources/0/0
20/07/11 18:15:19 INFO KafkaMicroBatchReader: Initial offsets: {"test":{"0":18}}
20/07/11 18:15:19 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-1fa35d7f-b356-4806-9ee7-658ef48c837d--2088528104-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 18.
20/07/11 18:15:19 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to s3a://checkpoint/offsets/0 using temp file s3a://checkpoint/offsets/.0.a7a4e7f3-7e4a-433f-8532-23d6179c3b98.tmp
20/07/11 18:15:19 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file s3a://checkpoint/offsets/.0.a7a4e7f3-7e4a-433f-8532-23d6179c3b98.tmp to s3a://checkpoint/offsets/0
20/07/11 18:15:19 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Committed offsets for batch 0. Metadata OffsetSeqMetadata(0,1594480519101,Map(spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass -> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider, spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion -> 2, spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy -> min, spark.sql.streaming.aggregation.stateFormatVersion -> 2, spark.sql.shuffle.partitions -> 200))
20/07/11 18:15:20 INFO KafkaMicroBatchReader: Partitions added: Map()
20/07/11 18:15:20 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 171.85213 ms
20/07/11 18:15:20 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 23.189288 ms
```

i went inside the checkpoint dir and modified the data and it started processing from the beginning!
there must be a config that does the same..

Comment: delete the checkpoint .. if you want to read from starting & as long as checkpoint is there it will read data from where it left of previously.

Comment: deleting the checkpoint does not work, it resumes at the latest offset

Comment: can you post the complete logs.. after deleting checkpoint directory ?

Comment: i added the logs to the main post

Comment: can you also show me kafka data & i think it is reading from beginning .. is it not ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So annonying... i mis-spelled the option `startingOffset`

the correct way to spell it is:

```
   .option("startingOffsets","earliest")
```

now it works.

Comment: beware that if the consumer-group already exists, this param won't have any effect, since it will seek the consumer's current offset. This only works with unregistered consumer groups

Comment: good point, noted

Comment: You can also take a look at the seek operation. Different than subscribe, it allows you to specify a partition and an offset to start from. Glad you fixed this mate. You can mark your own answer as valid; )

Comment: Good point... only ```s``` missing in that word .. :)

Comment: @thebluephantom I don't really know which answer you are referring to (my comment or OPs answer?)

Comment: may be confusing, but the offset param is futile when a consumer group is already registered: it will seek its current offset and continue from there.

Comment: @aran   the manual is indeed confusing. I am going to check again tomorrow. Sp St St is an abstraction layer on top of KAFKA. It states:  For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off. But the questioner want when new query started. In addition we need not use Consumer Groups from KAFKA afaik.

Comment: you don't need to use it, but when subscribing I confirm you kafka will give it an id. Streams, Spark,... set a higuer level of abstraction, but the core is the same one: if your consumer group is registered on the consumer_offsets topic, then auto.offset.reset does nothing

Comment: take a look here:https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#auto.offset.reset

auto.offset.reset
What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):

Comment: Note these sentences: "when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist" - This means "what to do when the consumer is not registered, or its offsets have been deleted". If the consumer id already exists, the auto.offset.reset parameter is totally futile

Comment: OK, then my understanding is OK, thx

Comment: Thanks to you mate!

Comment: I'm just here for the piano (no really, i don't know about these abstractions and hippie methods, cant help there)

Comment: @thebluephantom the only reason to clear the checkpoint is if your query used that checkpoint at all.

Comment: @coding_potato the question was not well formulated, probably lost in translation case. cheers